# Use rails stylesheet_link_tag based on path || controller?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application layout I have this conditional which helps deciding what stylesheet to use based on existence of current_user:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', id: "maincss" %>
<% else %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'session', media: 'all', id: "maincss" %>
<% end %>
```

But how can I specify which stylesheet to use based on the url?

For example, I want to use a 'password_reset.css' file for this path

```
get '/set/:password_reset_token' => 'password_resets#edit'
```

Comment: You can use following 
`<% if current_page?(controller: 'password_resets', action: 'edit') %>
  ## Include your stylesheet here it will only get loaded for password_reset controller's edit action
<% end %>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I do in my projects:

In the layout file, add a `yield` method like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    ...
    <%= yield(:head) %>
  </head>
  ...
```

In any view page (.erb file) that needs a custom CSS, I would add something like this at the top of the page.

```
 <% content_for :head do %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom_css_filename', media: 'all' %>
 <% end %>
```

This way stylesheet will go in the right place only for that page.

**Note:**

If you want to include a custom stylesheet for every single URL in your application, you should use what is suggested in the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag *([params[:controller], params[:action]] + (params[:id] || '').split('/')) %>
```

If you are okay with using `password_resets.css` instead of `password_reset.css`

Note: You may get a few unwanted link tags as well, which may result in harmless(except to logs) 404 responses